# When querying in Apache IoTDB Version 0.13.3, why results are duplicated for crertain timestamp ranges?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

My Apache IoTDB version is 0.13.3. Why are there duplicate data timestamps and values when querying data? The query statement I used is `select X1 from root.ops.K01 order by time desc`.
The result of `X1` should be either `true` or `false`, and the results are consistently repeated within specific timestamps (the duplicates are continuous). I need to determine whether this issue is related to the data type I have stored or the query statement I have used, and how to address it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a old version bug of Apache IoTDB. Since Version 0.13.3 is no longer maintained, and the `order by time desc` has bug that has been fixed in the newer version, it is recommended to upgrade to newer version (recommended you to upgrade to version 1.3).